# Why concurrent modification exception will not be thrown in the concurrent package?

Tags: java, java-collections-api

Classes like `ConcurrentHashmap` will not throw this exception; why? What are they doing internally to avoid this exception? How can I prevent this for all classes in the concurrent API?

Comment: Read the source code.  You can find it using Google; e.g. search for "ConcurrentHashmap source"

Comment: Those classes are designed to operate correctly in the presence of concurrent modification; that's their whole point.  There's no one specific thing they do internally; you'll have to look at their source code.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent collections implementations Iterators do not throw ConcurentModificationException because this is API's requirement, see java.util.concurrent package javadocs. Different implementations use different techniques to achieve that, eg creating a snapshot of the state of the collection. You can see JDK source code for implementation details.